# Iterable result from Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, iterator, jdbctemplate

Spring [JdbcTemplate](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) conveniently returns query results as single value, single row and collection. My application processes the result successively and only one time so I don't want to load memory with unnesessary accumulation. Neeed something like an `Iterator`. Tried this:

```
    try (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("jdbc-context.xml")) {
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.getBean("dataSource");

        JdbcTemplate jоdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        SqlRowSet rs = jоdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("select rownum from dual connect by rownum <= ?", 15);

        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        }
    }
```

But seems `SqlRowSet` is a disconnected version of Java standard [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), and in the implementation the query result is still accumulated first.

How to obtain iterable one-pass query result out of a `JdbcTemplate` without accumulation?

**SOLUTION**

As it was suggested by @GPI

```
    try (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("jdbc-context.xml")) {
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.getBean("dataSource");

        JdbcTemplate jоdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        ResultSetExtractor<Boolean> rse = new ResultSetExtractor<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public Boolean extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

                while(rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        jоdbcTemplate.query("select rownum from dual connect by rownum <= ?", new Integer[] {15}, rse);
    }
```

At least it works. Seems there's no more natural solutions. Will probably go back to standard JDBC and `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to accumulate anything on the "Spring side" of the code, then your easiest option is to call [`query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-) using a [`ResultSetExtractor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html)

The ResultSetExtractor is fed with the JDBC `ResultSet` which you can iterate from.

There is no way, as far as I know, to have an Iterable and not cache the SQL content somehow (iterables can re-create as many iterator as the caller wants, which means it has to be able to "remember" everything).

That said, the SQL driver itself may or may not be caching stuff itself, which is another discussion, that is not related to Spring.

You should read your SQL Driver's documentation to look for possible optimizations about that (fetch sizes, forward only scrollability, ...) and if need be, use a Spring `PreparedStatementCreator` to change the JDBC options that Spring uses to build the query.